# How to handle the javascript alert using webdriver with IEDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, alerts

With the selenium IEwebdriver, the webdriver Alert class methods are not working ... This issue seems specific to the IE browser, while in chrome,ff etc this works well.

Any workarounds that we can use to handle the js alerts using IEWebdriver ..?

I tried with the javascriptexecutor method too as below

```js
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.alert = function(msg){return true;};");  
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.prompt = function(msg) { return true; }");        
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

But no luck :(

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" The `Alert` methods are not globally broken; the WebDriver project has tests run on every commit on five different versions of IE, which are all passing, and which all include tests for alerts.

Comment: Hi Jim, i have this well popular piece of code                                                              Alert alt = driver.switchTo().alert();                    alt.accept(); and this looks not able to do the expected action on the JS alert comes in my application...and i see this problem only when i work on IE9 with iewebdriver... but in chrome it looks all fine ..  This is the problem am facing...

Answer (score 2):

In java we do it like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

Above code will implicitly wait for an alert. It will throw a TimeoutException if alert is not present.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Above code switches to alert popup and clicks OK. If alert is not present then it will throw NoAlertPresentException.

Hope it helps.