# Selenium IE11 Alert pop up handle does not work for close browser popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

**Issue:**
I am using IE11 with Selenium Webdriver, When I try to close the IE browser, I get a "Message From WebPage" popup display, I am trying to click "OK" but Alert handle does not work, It doesn't click "OK".

Selenium version: 3.12.0
IEDriverServer (32bit) version: 3.12.0

```
public void selectReqFolder() throws Exception {

    windowHandle = new WindowsHandle();
    //Clicking here open new child window 
    driver.findElement(Contract_File_Action_Copy_Frwd_Trnsction_button_Solcitation_Link).click();
    //Window handle method, switch focus on to child window and does all the task in there
    windowHandle.windowsHandle();
    //Using window handles to switch to parent window
    Set<String> s1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
    // Now we will iterate using Iterator to go over the totoal windows
    Iterator<String> I1 = s1.iterator();
    // List of the windows
    String parent = I1.next();
    String child_window = I1.next();
    **[![// Here we will compare if parent window 
    driver.switchTo().window(parent);
    //Closing the broswer
            driver.close();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
         //Handeling Alert
         Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        // Capturing alert message.    
        String alertMessage= driver.switchTo().alert().getText();   
        //To click on OK button of the alert
         driver.switchTo().alert().accept();][1]][1]**
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I would navigate to another page before closing... then use ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent() before switching to it.  That driver.close() call may be preventing your switchto calls.

Comment: I guess you'd also have to deal with driver.get() timeout, too.  It's going to throw that eventually because the alert will prevent it.  This prompt is from an onunload handler. (or beforeunload)

Comment: `driver.close()` means close the webdriver. I think that's the reason why the accept alert option not be executed. You can take @pcalkins's advice and try it again. You can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020468/how-to-handle-the-javascript-alert-using-webdriver-with-iedriver).